# The submenu is present in the UI (I'm able to see it). But, when I try to access it programmatically, I'm not getting that submenu

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

We are having a view, with pulldownmenu items (Group by, Grouped by).
'Group by' has sub-menu which are the columns in the views. When any of the submenu is selected, THe view entries will be grouped with the column and also there will be a entry added to 'Group by' Menu.

We are having a util method of signature:

```
public static void clickPullDownMenuItem(String viewID, String menu){
display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    IViewPart viewPart = getView(viewID);
    MenuManager mainMenuManager = (MenuManager) viewPart.getViewSite().getActionBars().getMenuManager();
    IContributionItem[] items = mainMenuManager.getItems();
    //iterate to through the items and invoke the action of the item.
  }
  Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

I use the below calls to simulate the same.

```
1. clickPullDownMenuItem(viewID, "Group by/Resource")
2. clickPullDownMenuItem(viewID, "Grouped by/Resource")
```

After the first statement is executed I am able to see the 'Resource' entry in the 'Grouped by' menu.
But, when the second statement is being executed, I'm getting no items under 'Grouped by' in the above method.

The thing I don't understand is the submenu is present in the UI (I'm able to see it). But, when I try to access it programmatically, I'm not getting that submenu.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `findUsingPath` to find a contribution item matching a path - particularly one containing a '/':

```
IMenuManager manager = viewPart.getViewSite().getActionBars().getMenuManager();

IContributionItem item = manager.findUsingPath(menu);
```

Comment: Greg, Thanks for commenting.
I guess I did not explain you the problem, correctly.

There are 2 menu items:
Group by and Grouped by.
'group by' inturn has many submenus and 'resource' is one among them.
The Steps I do is:
1) Find the 'resource' submenu under 'Group by'. (I'm able to do this).
2) click 'resource'. (I'm able to do this also). When I click 'resource', this 'resource' submenu will be added to 'Grouped by' menu as submenu. (This is the feature I'm testing).
3) After I clicked 'Resource', In the Eclipse application UI I'm able to see the 'Resource' submenu under 'Grouped by' Menu.

Comment: But, in my program, When I get the MenuManager instance from the view and check whether the menu item is avaiable, there is no 'Resource' submenu under that.

Why is this mismatch? Why am I able to see in the UI, not programmatically?